# Insertar desde JavaScript Etiqueta Xhtml

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml

Buen dia, mi problema es que mediante un script quiero visualizar etiquetas XHTML y mandarlas a una etiqueta div, pero al momento de mandar a visualizarcon el metodo "elemto.innerHTML" la etiqueta "" de JSF no se me grafica e leido que es un problema por que InnerHTMl no entiende etiquetas XHTML sabe alguien como visualizar etiquetas XHTML desde Javascript? se agredecera todo tipo de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado al momento de graficar es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando me deberia cargar los datos asi seria corecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna forma de visualizar estas etiquetas JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo tu pregunta, me parece que estás utilizando ambas cosas a la inversa. Es decir, resulta más sencillo (según la experiencia) utilizar JS desde XHTML que XHTML desde JS. Recordando que no es lo mismo que un HTML convencional.

En este sentido, ¿por qué no cargas directamente el XHTML y solo le agregas un atributo para no visualizarlo? Pienso en un **style="display: none;"**. Posteriormente lo visualizas por medio de una acción de JS, cambiando el estado a **display:block;**.

Espero haber contribuido a solucionar tu problema. ¡Saludos!

PS. Revisa el comportamiento de tu página desde la consola del navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Alexis Alcantara entiendo el concepto de ocultar y visualizar un elemento html pero yo nesesito insertar ya que al momento de insertar cargaria un dato de un objeto javascript
en este caso una fecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer click en la fecha este quiero que se cargue como parametro al metodo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna forma de hacerlo Ayuda por favor